# 3 threads two handlers?

Tags: android, multithreading

Situation: I have mainActivity which is responsible for updates on the screen. I have created a thread1 which receives data(packages) from sensor. For now I'm sending packages(using handler) back to mainActivity. When packages are received from thread1 I start Thread2 (from main) to decode them. Decoded data are sent back to main to do the rest.

Questions:

1. is this sequence any good: mainActivity - thread1 - mainActivity - thread2 - mainActivity?
2. maybe it would be better to decode it in main (packages are with 8 variables)?
3. Or maybe: mainActivity - thread1 - thread2 - mainActivity? is better to create a Handler in Thread2?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use the same thread for decoding as well ?

Comment: decoding takes time (cheking every variable, finding package start, needed value...) and I need to receive data continually.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your code in one asynctask you only need one thread because they don't need to run at the same time,  even the second depends to the first response.